# Calculation of the integral related to the gravitational shock wave

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, integration

The following integral
$$\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{\cos{\left(\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}s\right)}}{\sqrt{\cosh{s}-\cos{\theta}}}\,ds$$
can be found in the paper

> Tevian Dray and Gerard 't Hooft, *The gravitational shock wave of a massless particle*, Nuclear Physics B **253** (1985) 173--188, doi:[10.1016/0550-3213(85)90525-5](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0550-3213%2885%2990525-5).

They write that they "have not attempted to perform the integration explicitly". Was this integral ever calculated explicitly?

Comment: Do you mean to find closed form or just numeric approximation?

Comment: Wolfram alpha and sage don't seem to know how to compute this integral exactly.

Comment: @joro I mean to find a closed form, if this is possible.

Comment: See Conical Function http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConicalFunction.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A closed form exists in Gradshteyn and Ryzhik, 8.842.1.

> As a comment to this answer:
>
> Referring to the Gradshteyn and Ryzhik, the following result is given in http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9408169 (On Gravitational Shock Waves in Curved Spacetimes, by K. Sfetsos):
>   $$\int \limits_0^\infty \frac{\cos{(\sqrt{c-1/4}\,s)}}{\sqrt{\cosh{s}-\cos{\theta}}}\,ds=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}\cosh{(\sqrt{c-1/4}\,\pi)}}F\left(\frac{1}{2}-i\sqrt{c-1/4},\frac{1}{2}+i\sqrt{c-1/4},1,\cos^2{\frac{\theta}{2}}\right)=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}\cosh{(\sqrt{c-1/4}\,\pi)}}P_{-1/2+i\sqrt{c-1/4}}(-\cos{\theta}).
> $$

Comment: Would you mind sharing it with those of us who don't have access to the book? In Google Book's preview the page with with the formula is unfortunately omitted.

Comment: See also http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConicalFunction.html

Comment: If this is in terms of the Legendre function of the first kind (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_function), then it's like saying "Erf is the solution to the integral...". Although one _can_ (as usual) reduce to a certain hypergeometric function, which I guess as explicit as one can usually get in these cases.